# Role of Local Routing Header (LRH) in RoCEv2

Tags: rdma

In the RoCEv2 specification (Annex 17)

https://www.infinibandta.org/ibta-specifications-download/

the header BTH+ includes the Local Routing Header (LRH). The routing though is done with IP. Is there any use for the LRH ?

Are the source and destination local IDs used somewhere or are they set to 0 ?

Comment: Did you even read the document? "_All references in the Base Specification to the LRH and its fields are Not Applicable to RoCEv2 ports._"

Comment: I saw that after, but does that mean there is no LRH in the header ?

Answer (score 1):

RoCEv2 packets do not include an LRH. They include an Ethernet MAC header instead, an IP header (which takes the role of the IB GRH header), a UDP header, and the BTH header: [image: Annex 17: Figure 5 RoCEv2 Packet Format]

Comment: Are you certain ? In the above figure it doesn't say BTH (base transport header), it says BTH+.  I know that the GRH does not appear, but I think the LRH is there ...

Comment: I'm not sure what the plus means, but I suspect it means the optional headers that come after BTH for certain operations, such as DETH or AtomicETH.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to look at some headers and verify.